# Float package not working with H command

Tags: floats

This is the relevant piece of code including preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[Η]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth,height = \textheight, keepaspectratio]{/Users/rohanthakrar/Documents/University/Third Year/Graph Theory/Assessment/Images/total_colouring_table.jpg}
\caption{Edges and Vertices and their corresponding colours in a proper total colouring}
\label{table:TC}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

From this I am getting the error 'Unknown float option'. I don't understand why I am getting this as I am using the float package in my preamble.

Comment: you have not provided a usable example that shows your problem. In particular the `figure` environment is not predefined by latex it is defined by the document class which you have omited so we can not see the issue or test answers.

Comment: Off-topic: I wouldn't use a label of the form `\label{table:TC}` for a `figure` environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edited the post now so you can see the document class

Comment: @Mico the figure is a table

Comment: why not use `table` rather than `figure`  in that case? (even if you include it as an image if you want it numbered in sequence with tables, then you should use the table environment)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the table I wanted to construct was too difficult for me in Latex and it was more efficient to just create it in word and include it as an image.

Comment: yes sure but that doesn't matter to the reader so it would be more usual to use `\begin{table}`  so it is numbered as a table and kept in sequence with other tables. The fact that you use \includegraphics rather than tabular is just an implementation detail that does not need to affect the visible document numbering

Comment: @TopCruzer - What's stopping you from using a `table` environment as a wrapper for the `\includegraphics` directive?

Comment: @Mico I didn't know you could do that, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Option should be H (ASCII LATIN H) but you have used
Η (U+0397 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ETA)

Comment: Wow good spot thank you